# Can Git stashes have a GPG signature?

Tags: git, gitlab, gnupg, git-stash

My GitLab project is configured to require GPG signatures for all pushed commits.  However, when I try to push a stash up to GitLab, it's rejected with the message "Commit must be signed with a GPG key".

According to other threads on this forum, the gitconfig setting "commit.gpgsign=true" results in commits and stashes automatically being signed.  I'm guessing those posts may have meant "commits and tags"?

A stash is just a changeset that hasn't been committed to any particular branch, so I wouldn't expect that there's anything mechanically preventing a stash from being signed.  Any ideas?

Comment: `git stash` makes its commits without going through `git commit` (it short-circuits it with `git commit-tree` instead), and the signing machinery is in the other code path. In general it's best to avoid `git stash` as much as possible though: just use regular commits on regular branches (a new branch if you want).

Answer (score 3):

Commit the stashed commit to a temporary branch instead

```bash
git checkout -b temp-branch  # from current branch
git stash pop                # or selective index
git commit -m "message"
git push                     # temporary branch is saved
```

You can optionally delete the branch later, though putting the date in its name and keeping it around can be helpful depending on development style